# nginx and uwsgi issue on EC2

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have my nginx and uwsgi setup following this tutorial:

http://panta.info/blog/3/how-to-install-and-configure-nginx-uwsgi-and-django-on-ubuntu.html

I'm getting the following error:

```
Thu Sep 26 17:33:11 2013 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/repo/mysite/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

but when I do this, it works:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>>> get_wsgi_application()
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x7f3b23281790>
>>>
```

Is there something else i'm missing? I've been trying to debug this for some time, any help is appreciated!

I also referred to this page to no avail:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a path issue

in you uwsgi ini file can you try adding

```
home=<abs path to your virtualenv>
```

so if you followed the tutorial exactly it would be

```
home=/home/USER/projects/venv
```